# Can't access elements in array using key

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to get a list of all pages on a wordpress site and access their ID. I can get a list of pages using the [get_pages()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages) function. When I try to access any of the elements with their keys, it doesn't interpret.

For example, the following code wouldn't work:

```
$pages = get_pages();

foreach ($pages as $page) {
  $ID = $page['ID'];
}
```

But, if I do this:

```
$pages = get_pages();

foreach($pages as $page) {
  foreach ($page as $key => $value) {
    echo("<p>$key</p>");
  }
}
```

It clearly prints out ID as a valid key.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide the error message, and a `var_dump` or pages.

Comment: See [the manual](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages) _The returned array is an array of "page" objects_ **The manual is always a good place to look when things go wrong.** So `$ID = $page->ID;` is probably what you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do this

```
$pages = get_pages();

foreach($pages as $page) {
  foreach ($page as $key => $value) {
    echo("<p>$key</p>");
  }
}
```

So the above $pages becomes associated array, and you can access key with associative array. Associated arrays are used in php for KEY VALUE PAIR

So you can use

```
$pages = get_pages(); 
  foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
  echo  $page->ID;

}
```

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly. When I create my own array by declaring my own keys for elements I can access it with the normal array syntax. How is that different to this example?

Comment: I dint got you... elaborate more please

Comment: See @Pawan Kumar answer.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for accpeting my solution. I hope it helped everyone in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Because `get_pages()` returns an array of "pages" OBJECTS `$page` in the `foreach` loop will be a page object therefore you need to use the `->` to address the `ID` property.

```
$pages = get_pages(); 
foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
    echo  $page->ID;
}
```

Comment: Do or Do Not, there is no "Try" padawan. A **good answers** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.

Comment: Ok . Thanks @RiggsFolly.

Comment: Now it is better. Thank you again. @RiggsFolly.

Comment: Thank you. I thought that it was returning an array of arrays, not objects. Dumb mistake.

Answer (score -1):

Give an example of the array(multidimensional,key->value,simple array,etc).
Let's assume:

```
//simple array parsing
$pages = array('one','two','three');
foreach ($pages  as $page) {
  echo "Current value: $page.\n";
}

//key-> value parsing
$pages   = array(
"one" => 1,
"two" => 2,
"three" => 3
);

foreach ($pages as $k => $v) {
  echo "\$pages[$k] => $v.\n";
}

 //multidimensional array parsing
 $pages = array();
 $pages[0][0] = "one";
 $pages[0][1] = "two";
 $pages[1][0] = "three";

 foreach ($pages as $v1) {
    foreach ($v1 as $v2) {
       echo "$v2\n";
    }
 }
```

See references on [link]http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I got the whole situation wrong though, the array actually contained objects, not arrays.